# How does Default Equality Comparer compare special characters

Tags: c#, linq

```
namespace LINQ_check
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<Person> people1 = LoadSampleData();
            people1 = people1.OrderBy<Person, string>((Person i) => i.LastName.Substring(0, 1)).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
            foreach (var VARIABLE in people1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE.ToString());
            }
        }

        public static List<Person> LoadSampleData()
        {
            var output = new List<Person>();

            output.Add(new Person { FirstName = "0Tida", LastName = "](Combey", Birthday = Convert.ToDateTime("2/25/1970"), YearsExperience = 20 });
            output.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Joe", LastName = ")Combey", Birthday = Convert.ToDateTime("2/25/1970"), YearsExperience = 12 });
            output.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Sue", LastName = "Storm", Birthday = Convert.ToDateTime("1/3/1970"), YearsExperience = 1 });
            output.Add(new Person { FirstName = "1Sara", LastName = "Jones", Birthday = Convert.ToDateTime("3/6/1970"), YearsExperience = 8 });
            output.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Jamie", LastName = "0Doe", Birthday = Convert.ToDateTime("2/18/1970"), YearsExperience = 7 });
            output.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Mary", LastName = "&Smith", Birthday = Convert.ToDateTime("1/23/1970"), YearsExperience = 16 });
            output.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Mary", LastName = "&Smith", Birthday = Convert.ToDateTime("1/23/1970"), YearsExperience = 15 });

            return output;
        }

        public static List<Person> LoadSampleData1()
        {
            var output = new List<Person>();

            output.Add(new Person { FirstName = "aaa", LastName = "bbbb", Birthday = Convert.ToDateTime("2/25/1970"), YearsExperience = 20 });
            output.Add(new Person { FirstName = "tttt", LastName = "linq", Birthday = Convert.ToDateTime("2/25/1970"), YearsExperience = 12 });
            return output;
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int YearsExperience { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
        public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";

        public override string? ToString()
        {
            return $"{FirstName} {LastName} ({Birthday.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")}): Experience {YearsExperience}";
        }
    }
}
```

If I do this kind of sorting, the output is:

```
Joe )Combey (25/02/1970): Experience 12
0Tida ](Combey (25/02/1970): Experience 20
Mary &Smith (23/01/1970): Experience 15
Mary &Smith (23/01/1970): Experience 16
Jamie 0Doe (18/02/1970): Experience 7
1Sara Jones (06/03/1970): Experience 8
Sue Storm (03/01/1970): Experience 1
```

It has to sort the following items (), ], &, &, 0, J, S)

I am truing to understand why did it sort the way it did because as I am checking the decimal numbers of the characters it should have sorted like this:
`&` then `&` then `)` then `]` etc…

Comment: Post a small example with only enough code to reproduce the problem. If you want to know why the surnames were or the *characters* were sorted this way, create a `string[]` with those values. Right now it's hard to understand what the data is showing, because you sort by the last name but display the *first name* at the start of each string.

Comment: String comparison is not char comparison, even if your strings contain only one char. You'd get your expected result if you'd use `OrderBy((Person i) => i.LastName[0])`

Comment: As for how strings are ordered, it's based on the lexical order of the current locale, not the Unicode code point. There's nothing special about `(` or `&` in Unicode. To force sorting by code point you'd have to pass `StringComparer.Ordinal` to `OrderBy`

Comment: Thank you for the answer @PanagiotisKanavos
sorry for the stupid question
where can I find/check/get the current locale?

Comment: @EricMovsessian `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentInfo`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=net-8.0